how to properly delete an item in datatable.net in react?
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
// import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min';
import "datatables.net-dt/js/dataTables.dataTables";
import "datatables.net-dt/css/dataTables.dataTables.min.css";
import "datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis";
import "datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5";
import "datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print";
import "datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons";
// import 'jszip';
import JSZip from 'jszip'; 
import 'pdfmake';
// import 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
// import 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';
import pdfMake from "pdfmake/build/pdfmake";
import pdfFonts from "pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts";

window.JSZip = JSZip;
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;


const MasterDataTable = (prop) => {
  const { tableId, tableData } = prop
  const dataTableRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("tableData",tableData)

 
        if(tableData?.length > 0){

        dataTableRef.current = $(`#${tableId}`).DataTable({
            pagingType: 'full_numbers',
            pageLength: 10,
            processing: true,
            
            destroy:true,
            retrieve:true,
            
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            // buttons: ['copyHtml5', 'csvHtml5', 'excelHtml5', 'pdfHtml5', 'print'],
            orientation: tableData[0] && tableData[0].length > 4 ? 'landscape' : 'portrait', // Set orientation based on column count
            pageSize: tableData[0] && tableData[0].length > 4 ? 'A3' : 'A4', // Adjust page size based on the number of columns
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'copyHtml5',
                    exportOptions: {
                      columns: ':visible', 
                      modifier: {
                        page: 'all'
                      },
                      format: {
                          body: (data, row, column, node) => {
                            console.log(3)
                          // Dynamically handle the Status column
                              if ($(node).closest('td').hasClass('status-column')) {
                              return $(data).find('input').is(':checked') ? 'True' : 'False';
                              }
                              return $(node).text().trim();
                          }
                      },
                      stripHtml: true,
                    },                  
                },
                {
                extend: 'csvHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible',     
                    modifier: {
                    page: 'all'
                    },
                    format: {
                      body: (data, row, column, node) => {
                      // Dynamically handle the Status column
                        if ($(node).closest('td').hasClass('status-column')) {
                        return $(data).find('input').is(':checked') ? 'True' : 'False';
                        }
                        return $(node).text().trim();
                      }
                    },
                    stripHtml: true,
                }
                },
                {
                  extend: 'excelHtml5',
                  exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible',
                    modifier: {
                      page: 'all'
                    },
                    format: {
                      body: (data, row, column, node) => {
                      // Dynamically handle the Status column
                        if ($(node).closest('td').hasClass('status-column')) {
                        return $(data).find('input').is(':checked') ? 'True' : 'False';
                        }
                        return $(node).text().trim();
                      }
                    },
                    stripHtml: true,
                  }
                },
                {
                  extend: 'pdf',
                  exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible', 
                    stripHtml: false,
                    modifier: {
                      page: 'all'
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    exportOptions: {
                      columns: ':visible', 
                      stripHtml: false,
                      modifier: {
                        page: 'all'
                      }
                    }
                  },
                'colvis',

              ],
              initComplete: ()=> {
                // $(`#${tableId}`).addClass('table table-bordered table-hover toggle-circle custom-table table');
            }
            });
            console.log(`DataTable with ID #${tableId} initialized.`);
  
    
    }



  }, [tableId, tableData]);

};

export default MasterDataTable;

Above is the generic code for datatable that will be used on different tables. The problem is that when i delete an item from the table it gives this error:

Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

The problem seems to be that i am directly manipulating the DOM, so when there is one item less in the table then it gives this error.
Please help on how to resolve this error and properly delete the item from the table.
EDIT:
I used a unique key={item?.id} in the tr tag of the table and it resolved the error. but now the issue is that the items in the table are not properly removed even after deleting an item. for example after deleting an item, going to next page and previous page again (where the item was), it reappears again in the table. ofcourse on hard refresh the table is updated. but thats not what i want. any help please?
EDIT: deleting an item from table was working perfectly without the datatables.net library previously. but now it is not working fine. i guess the problem is that the datatable is not refreshing/reinitializing properly after destruction.

where is the code that removes items from your data?  my guess is that the problem is in either how you remove data or how you pass it to the datatable.

@sparkJ it is a simple table with tr td th tags. i fetch that table using tableId. in that table is delete functionality. after deleting an item, the whole table data is fetched from database again. without the datatables.net library (i.e. simple table), the delete functionality was working perfect. but now the datatable is not refreshing properly due to datatables.net usage.
